# Clear typeahead field

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

how could I clear a typeahead field in a `focusout` event?

The following jQuery code doesn´t seem to work in a typeahead field:

```
$( "#field" ).focusout(function() {
    $(this).val("");
});
```

Comment: Seems to be working fine on my machine. Using jQ 2.0 and IE11 and Chrome 39. Please post your input element and other event that are attached to it.

Comment: $("#field").on("blur", function() { $(this).val(""); }); ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try with this, example here in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kynrk5ah/)

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead().bind('typeahead:close', function () {
    $('.typeahead').typeahead('val', '');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply,my solution is close to this one you passed:    function clear(field{
 $("#"+field).typeahead('val', '');
}

Comment: It seems the event is now 'typeahead:close' not 'typeahead:closed' not sure if this is a typo or whether it changed in later versions of typeahead - https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md#datasets

Comment: This is outdated and no longer works. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/45881480/5551593

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer is now out of date.  See the [latest Typeahead documentation](https://github.com/twitter/typeahead.js/blob/master/doc/jquery_typeahead.md) to see that trapping the "close" event and setting the value of the input are different.  Here's an equivalent, updated answer:

```
$('.typeahead').typeahead().bind('typeahead:close', function() {
    $('.typeahead').typeahead('val', '');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the answers, but the **close** event did not work for me maybe my setting or something has deprecated. so I have written this code and it worked well.

```
$('#typeahead-id').typeahead().bind('typeahead:selected', function() {
    $('#typeahead-id').typeahead('val', '')
});
```